# Techniques how to join two wearable-flexible pcb parts

Tags: flexible

I am looking at pictures/videos that show people wear fully flexible PCBs, and I wonder how they join their ends together. They never show the part where the flexible parts are joined together, so I am pretty sure the pictures of the project are still a concept and not an actual solution.

Example 1: The join part is not visible:

[image: flexible wearable pcb join]
[Source](https://mvp-consultancy.com/2019/08/06/an-intro-to-flex-pcbs/)

Example 2: The join part is not visible:

[image: flexible wearable pcb no join]
[Souce](https://5e-project.eu/portfolio/elastic-wearable-ecg-skin-patch/)

Given the fact that there are not many such pictures, makes me believe there is no practical way to join two flex pcb together.
Closest practical thing I found is someone gluing magnets on the pcb and then join it together, but he is not even using flexible substrate, its just bendable plastic. This is also not a good solution since the glue might be toxic for the skin, and if non-toxic glue is used, they are not as strong as toxic glues, and it will fall off...

[image: flexible pcb join]
[Source](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5-jkxVnT6PA)

The standard seems to be using rubber-like straps/bands for watches, and never join flexible pcbs together:

[image: pcb wearable]
[Source](https://www.engadget.com/2011-09-28-a-diy-arduino-watch-thats-actually-wearable-still-wont-win-yo.html?guccounter=1&guce_referrer=aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbS8&guce_referrer_sig=AQAAAEdJsYQh_9Rt7PyHj4lKJO-I4-iKRwZ244CjcpszgXX75c5t7oBmn_w_cit9iPoBwaUOzt8JaIoJr58WF44vPSez4CF_3v-UHl3FCDRtOyEogYUKBoueyZsCzoamSw25vjv9ImRUKOnqmk9FGVGGBQFuPqvRCUWRLsg1r3gWowHI)

[image: pcb wearable]
[Source](https://cemse.kaust.edu.sa/sensors/news/kaustat-wireless-wearable-open-source-potentiostat-electrochemical-measurements)

Anyone know any practical way to join flexible pcbs together? Maybe there is a trick/solution or company that sells such solutions.

Comment: What is the application for this? You should take the entire product in consideration. Are there even any point in mounting only a flexible pcb around a persons arm like in the image shown? For a finished product, you still need to put it in some sort of enclosure etc, that could accommodate the "joining" part. Also, can't make a reliable flexible product like this. Flexing it enough times and the solder joints (or something else) will crack, as the components soldered on the PCB are not flexible. It can work for mounting the PCB **fixed** in a bent position, but not as a bracelet.

Comment: Surely any mechanical technique will work as long as you don't need an electrical connection (which you don't). For example you could cut a slit halfway across each end of the PCB, a different half on each end, and then interlock them together. (That mechanism surely has a name)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are looking for just a mechanical joint, I suggest standard jewelry hardware such as crimped ribbon clamps. They come in various widths and can accept clasps.

Note that flex PCBs by default are not intended for dynamic flexing applications and will tend to fail quickly if bent sharply or repeatedly.

Answer (score 2):

Joining two flex PCB is usually done with low profile 1-piece compression contacts. Both PCB should have a stiffener, one of them will have the contacts.
Soldering two such PCB together will create a stiff, fragile joint, which might not be suitable for a wearable product.
I have also seen pogo pins being used for this.